# Guardar la seleccion de un enum en un struct

Tags: c++

Intento que se pueda elegir un tipo de posicion de baloncesto y guardar la eleccion en *usuario.player*. En el codigo pretendo que se ingrese un numero por teclado y que se imprima la posicion correspondiente, pero creo que no estoy entiendo bien el funcionamiento de enum y struct. (crear otra variable para la seleccion no es lo que busco).
Gracias.

El error esta en el cin, que me da estos 3 errores: **" ningun operador ">>" coincide con estos operandos "**, **" el tipo 'usuario' no tiene un miembro sobrecargado 'operator ->' "** y **" '->usuario::player': el operando izquierdo tiene el tipo 'struct'; utilice '.' "**

```
typedef enum {
    base,
    pivot,
    alero
}posiciones;

typedef struct {
    int edad;
    char nombre[15];
    posiciones player;
}usuario;


int main()
{
    
    usuario one;
cout <<"\n(1 Base  2 Pivot  3 Alero)"<<endl<<Posicion;
    
    cin >> one.player;

    
    switch (one.player)
    {
    case base:
        cout << "base";
        break;

    case pivot: 
        cout << "pivot";
        break;

    case alero: 
        cout << "alero";
        break;

    default: break;
    }
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Buena pregunta, pero deberías explicar qué error te ha encontrado (error de compilación, el programa no funciona como esperas...)

Comment: Es verdad perdon editare la pregunta

Comment: Que es lo que esperas que pase cuando tratas de leer desde la terminal un `posiciones`??? Eso es algo que no esta definido, y si quieres que sea posible tienes que sobrecargar el operador: `std::istream& operator<<(std::istream&, posiciones&)`